# App Widget: Ripple effect lost on list item when background is added to outer layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-appwidget

This thing is driving me crazy. Here's how it works

**1. everything is set as default**

- ripple effect works
- list view item separator is visible

[image: original state]

**2. white background added to the widget layout**

- ripple lost
- list view item separator also gone
- looks like list item style has been removed

[image: white background]

### Here's the code

**main widget layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              ...
              android:background="@android:color/white" -- this line only applies for case 2
              android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding">

    <TextView
        ...
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <ListView
        ...
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true""/>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list item layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:id="@+id/widgetItem">

    <TextView
        ...
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:textColor="@color/negative_amount"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've spent a day trying all possible combinations but nothing helped. And I don't get the fact that unrelated background change to some layout around the list view completely alters the behaviour. WTF?

I would like to solve it in the cleanest way possible - e.i. no hacking with custom selectors. This should work straight out of the box if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a dark theme for your activity, so the ripple is white and thus not visible over a white background. The simplest solution is to use a light variant of the theme, which will cause the ripple to be black.

For example, if you're using an AppCompat theme, you can add this line to your `ListView`:

```xml
<ListView
    ...
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

You can also apply this to a view hierarchy, e.g.:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      ...
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

This will cause the theme to be used in the `LinearLayout` and all of its child views.

Also, you can specify a theme activity-wide or even app-wide by adding `android:theme` attribute to the `<activity>` or `<application>` tag to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I use Light theme in the application. But I tried your suggestion and set the theme to the list view / list view item to be sure and the behavior stayed the same - white widget background=no touch feedback at all, no widget background=ripple works fine (as I showed on screenshots).

Comment: It might be that themes don't affect ripple colors of a `ListView`. If you don't find any sensible solution to your problem, maybe you should consider switching to `RecyclerView`? That way you'll have better control of the list's behavior and appearance.